# Regular expression thingy

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create a custom regular expression. Which shall track that the first character of a username should be an alphabet.

Followed by alphanumeric or can have maximum one occurrence of a special character (`-` or `_`). I can check for username starts with the alphabet with this `^[a-zA-Z]+$` but not sure what to do to check at most one occurrence of a special character. Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Your rules are not quite clear, try `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$` It would be best if you explained the rules in better detail and provided sample valid/invalid strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thank for picking it up but some folks have actually get the gist of the story and it's sorted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match an upper or lowercase character from the start of the string `^[a-zA-Z]`, match zero or more times alphanumeric `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` followed by an optional hyphen or underscore `[-_]?`.

At the end match zero or more times alphanumeric `[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` until the end of the string.

[`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/p7DdJr/1)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood of your post, you want the following to match.

```
a-afdsafd
aafdsafd
aafdsa_fd
aafdsa-fd
aAfdsa-FD
```

And the following to not match:

```
aa-dsa-fd
aa-dsa_fd
-afdsafd
_afdsafd
```

Try `/^[a-z](?:(?![a-z]+[\-_])[\-_])?[a-z]+(?:(?<![a-z]+[\-_])[\-_]?)[a-z]+?$/i`

1. The `i` modifier enables case-insensitive matching.
2. The `^` and `$` anchors ensure that the entire string matches our regex.
3. `[a-z]` checks that the first character is an alphabet.
4. `(?:(?![a-z]+[\-_])[\-_])?)` looks ahead to check that there is no "special character" used later and if there is none, we optionally match one special character.
5. `[a-z]+` Match one or more alphabets.
6. `(?:(?<![a-z]+[\-_])[\-_]?)` does the same thing as 4 except it looks behind.
7. `[a-z]+?` Optionally match one or more alphabets.

https://regexr.com/3t86l

**Edit**: I noticed that `aAfdsaFd_` should also match. The above does not match this. Slightly modifying @Wiktor Stribiżew's comment, `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$` seems to work fine with all cases. That's cleaner and more efficient. All credit to @Wiktor Stribiżew.